# I need to assign a value following a specific string from a file into a variable in bash

Tags: bash

Hope you can help....

Bash related question...

I have a folder with 3 files in it

```
654321_static1.txt
123456_static2.txt
321654_static3.txt
```

I need to find a value in 123456_static2.txt (note the random numbers preceding the _static2.txt are random and will change and will be unknown to me but the directpry path is constant.)

inside this file -> 12345_static2.txt will be many lines of text but there will always be this string
serverUuid="34543n54353453ewrwer" - I need to assign the value within the quotes to a variable.

```
var=34543n54353453ewrwer
```

Also note if this makes a difference that serverUuid="34543n54353453ewrwer" may appear once or many times but will always be the same value

Appreciate any help you can offer..

Comment: We're here to help you fix your code, not write it for you. Include your best attempt (anything really) and people will help improve your understanding ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: look for variable assigments like `var=$( grep something file)`. Good luck.

Comment: To help you you should show your code and part of file where var Uuid="" is included. Maybe you need something like var=$(grep -m 1 "serverUuid" your_file.txt  | cut -d'"' -f2)

Answer (score 0):

i think this should work

```
variable=$(grep serverUuid (filename) | cut -d '"' -f 2)
```